# The following packages have been kept back _22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, 22.04

There are new updates for 22.04 and after entering the apt-get upgrade command. I got this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-generic
  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-22.04
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

I had the exact same packages that were kept back a while back when using 20.04. And solved it either manually doing

`apt-get install` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` of which i cannot recall which was used. Hence, could somebody let me know which is the "safer" solution or is there a new solution with 22.04?

**Update**

I went over to the Software Updater GUI and those 7 held back packages appeared and I was able to upgrade through the software updater without any problem. Weird thing was while in installation, snap popped up a couple of times.

Comment: You might have had similar issue as me - simultaneous upgrade of kernel and NVIDIA driver. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403264/ubuntu-20-04-wants-to-do-partial-upgrade-for-newest-kernel-upgrade

Comment: `apt-get install` is the command to install a package and needs you to specify a package. That won't solve your problem here. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade all your packages to the most recent version and will intelligently handle dependencies including deleting dependencies if needed. This could solve the problem. Remember to always run `sudo apt update` before you start any other tasks in `apt`

Comment: Raj and Nmath, thank you for the reply. As updated in my post, Software Updater didn't held back the packages, hence, i went ahead using it instead of running command thru the terminal. However, as mentioned, it was weird seeing snap popping up during installation. But when I typed snap list in the terminal, none of the packages appeared in the list.

Comment: It is likely that this is due to the new Phased Updates feature. It can be disabled or synchronized. There is more info in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force "packages \[that\] have been kept back" to be installed \[as\] "automatic"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat)